# Literary criticism handbook

Tags: style, creative-writing, novel, criticism

Can you point out some reference books on literary criticism – from a *theoretical* as well as *practical* point of view – to hone and systematize my skills, acquired through first-hand reading of lots of books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very good read which is informative and entertaining is, [How To Read Literature Like a Professor](http://amzn.to/2pIHDnL), by Thomas C. Foster.

Another very good book is [Literary Criticism: An Introduction to Theory and Practice](http://amzn.to/2pIGUmm)  by Charles Bressler.  A bit more academic, but quite good.

Answer (score 0):

One of my go-tos is "[Literary Theory: A Very Short Introduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199691347)" by Jonathan Culler. It's great for people who are new to literary theory, or for veterans that are looking to brush up on the basics.

Answer (score 0):

One of the standard introductions for university students is *Literary Theory: An Introduction* by Terry Eagleton.